eclipse-mosquitto ED25519 ca md too weak
I'm finding it very difficult to get the right combination of elements to have python paho-mqtt communicate securely with an eclipse-mosquitto container, although this question is only about the latter. I have control of both ends. I'm using ED25519 because that's what I use for another component of the same project, using lftp to upload files.
To create the self-signed certificates I did the following which resulted in no errors (Manjaro Linux)
openssl genpkey -algorithm ED25519 -out mydomainCA.key
openssl req -x509 -new -key mydomainCA.key -days 3650 -subj '/CN=mydomain' -out mydomainCA.crt

openssl genpkey -algorithm ED25519 -out mydomain_mqtt.key
openssl req -new -nodes -key mydomain_mqtt.key -subj '/CN=mqtt.mydomain.net' -out mydomain_mqtt.csr
openssl x509 -req -in mydomain_mqtt.csr -CA mydomainCA.crt -CAkey mydomainCA.key -CAcreateserial -days 365 -out mydomain_mqtt.crt

I put these into a private directory along with a set of client identity certificates for a test user and set docker-compose volume bound to to the target directory /mosquitto/config, as in this yaml. I also put mosquitto.conf there.
  mqtt:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    ports:
      - target: 8883
        published: 8883
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /etc/ssl/private/mqtt
        target: /mosquitto/config
        read_only: false

Here is mosquitto.conf:
log_type all

allow_anonymous false

protocol mqtt
listener 8883
protocol websockets

tls_version tlsv1.3
ciphers_tls1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256

cafile /mosquitto/config/mydomainCA.crt
keyfile /mosquitto/config/mydomain_mqtt.key
certfile /mosquitto/config/mydomain_mqtt.crt

require_certificate true
use_identity_as_username true

When I start the container docker-compose -f deploy/dragnet.yml up mqtt I get this output.
mqtt-1  | 1721764169: mosquitto version 2.0.18 starting
mqtt-1  | 1721764169: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
mqtt-1  | 1721764169: Opening websockets listen socket on port 8883.
mqtt-1  | 1721764169: Error: Unable to create websockets listener on port 8883.
mqtt-1 exited with code 1

If I remove the protocol websockets line I get a very different output.
mqtt-1  | 1721764272: mosquitto version 2.0.18 starting
mqtt-1  | 1721764272: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
mqtt-1  | 1721764272: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
mqtt-1  | 1721764272: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
mqtt-1  | 1721764272: Error: Unable to load server certificate "/mosquitto/config/mydomain_mqtt.crt". Check certfile.
mqtt-1  | 1721764272: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:14FFF18E:SSL routines:(UNKNOWN)SSL_internal:ca md too weak
mqtt-1 exited with code 1

With or without protocol websockets if I comment out the line certfile /mosquitto/config/mydomain_mqtt.crt it starts without error. Not that I have got it work, but at least the container runs.
It makes no difference if I use TLS 1.2 with the same ciphers, which it seems I'll need to do because of python paho-mqtt compatibility.
I have tried to use the privkey.pem file from letsencrypt instead of the mydomainCA.key. When I try that, I get a different error message.
mqtt-1  | 1721782812: Error: Unable to load server certificate "/mosquitto/config/mydomain_mqtt.crt". Check certfile.
mqtt-1  | 1721782812: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:14FFF0F7:SSL routines:(UNKNOWN)SSL_internal:unknown certificate type

That's all I've been able to figure out so far, but now I'm going in circles. It appears to be a difficult one to solve with incremental changes as it is hard to tell whether I'm going backwards or forwards.
Thanks,
Chris

I received a hint on another board recommending changing default_md to sha256. As far as I can tell, that is the default. I tried changing it and regenerating the certs which didn't change anything, and for fun I try sha512 as well.

The complaint is the certificate is signed with a SHA1 hash. That's the first thing you should validate. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42857704/175990

I tried adding the -sha256 option to all the req commands. The option was accepted but made no difference to the outcome. I also tried -sha512 option with the same result. As I mentioned before it appears to be the default for the recent versions of openssl.

Using the command openssl x509 -in server.crt -text -noout it tells me that both the signature and the public key are ED25519. No mention of SHA. The ED25519 signature is  64 bytes long whilst the ED25519 Public-Key is 32 bytes long.

It was easier to punt on this and go with my letsencrypt certs for this application and the server TLS appears to be working now, although I'm still dealing with some behind-the-nat naming issues with the domain. Now it's time to try client keys. Wish me luck!

I was not able to determine why the above setup didn't work. I found only one reference to ED25519 being used for mosquitto. Too bad it didn't work and it looks like I'll never know why. In the end, I used my letsencrypt certificates. I found references to 3 different combinations that worked, although I settled on the one provided in the official mosquitto blog.
On the other hand I've not been able to figure out how to make certificate-based user authentication work. It appears that people are doing it, but I can't find mention of it in the mosquitto documentation. I guess I'll use a password file. At least it won't be clear text now.

To whoever gave me the downvotes, if you had anything useful to contribute yourself then I could accept them gracefully, but downvotes to a new user with zero guidance just paints your as an asshole, IMHO.
